# Plotting Elliptical Orbits

Tags: python, numpy, ellipse, eclipse-kepler, orbital-mechanics

I am trying to plot elliptical orbits using python. Using formula 
r=a(1-e^2)/(1+ecos(theta)). The data points needed to be plotted are:

- values of a: 0.39, 0.72, 1.00, 1.52
- values of e: 0.205, 0.007, 0.017, 0.093
- values of theta (Degrees): 77.5, 132, 103, 336

Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def radius(r,deg,rad):
    a=np.array([0.39,0.72,1.00,1.52])
    e=np.array([0.205,0.007,0.017,0.093])
    deg=np.array([77.5,132,103,336])
    rad=(deg*np.pi)/180
    r=(a*(1-e**2))/(1+e*np.cos(rad))
    return r,deg,rad

plt.polar(rad, r)
plt.show()
```

The error I seem to get is NameError: name 'r' is not defined. Since I returned the function I don't understand why it is not defined.

Comment: where use radius function?

Comment: Why do you create a function and not use it?, Use the values directly:
 `a=np.array([0.39,0.72,1.00,1.52])
e=np.array([0.205,0.007,0.017,0.093])
deg=np.array([77.5,132,103,336])
rad=(deg*np.pi)/180
r=(a*(1-e**2))/(1+e*np.cos(rad))

plt.polar(rad, r)
plt.show()`

Comment: When executing the previous code I get the following: https://imgur.com/a/sHT13

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if your math and plot function is correct, but looking at your function `radius` you are pretty much hard coding  `a,e,deg` and returning `r,deg,rad`.
Since you are not passing any values / variables to the function, it needs to be
`radius()` and not `radius(r,deg,rad)`

Also, you need collect the values returned by function and then use that  for plotting.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def radius():
    a=np.array([0.39,0.72,1.00,1.52])
    e=np.array([0.205,0.007,0.017,0.093])
    deg=np.array([77.5,132,103,336])
    rad=(deg*np.pi)/180
    r=(a*(1-e**2))/(1+e*np.cos(rad))
    return r,deg,rad

r,deg,rad = radius()
plt.polar(rad, r)
plt.show()
```

**Figure**
[image]